# how to find the last instance of a setting in a config file

Tags: linux, perl, search, sed, awk

I am trying to figure out how to find the **last** entry of a string in multiple config files across a server.  Each of the strings will be in the /home/***usernamewouldbehere/public_html/typo3conf/localconf.php file

In short - the last entry in the config files will point to the database server the application is utilizing - and we need to know which accounts point to which db server.

While I can run something like this -

```
grep "$_db_host" /home/*/public_html/conf/localconf.php
```

It does not really help much because it gives us way to much information ... and not what we really need.

What i really need to know is the last entry of this string  $_db_host = 'xx'; and to sort them out in an export file

Since the config files may have multiple entries  (example below)

```
$_db_host = 'localhost';
$_db_host = '10.0.1.234';
```

It would be great to list in a file all of those that have the entry for 'localhost' 
and then list all of those that have the entry for '10.0.1.234' (or whichever server there may be there)  but even if I need to do that manually that would be great.

I am not sure how to get to it using Awk - ... and really stuck

What I am hoping for is something that would be piped as follows

```
db_host = localhost /home/username1/www/conf/localconf.php
db_host = localhost / home/username2/public_html/conf/localconf.php

db_host= '10.1.2.23' /home/username55/public_html/conf/localconf.php
```

hoping that helps you help me :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is a little unclear what you are asking.  Without going into perl or awk perhaps you could use something like

```
grep -H '$_db_host =' /home/*/public_html/typo3conf/localconf.php | tail -n 1
```

Or if you want the last in each file (bash syntax):

```
for i in (/home/*/public_html/typo3conf/localconf.php); do
   grep -H '$_db_host =' $i /dev/null | tail -1
done
```

If you want to categorize by the particular values of $_db_host you can use sort (either with or without the tail trick):

```
grep -H '$_db_host =' /home/*/public_html/typo3conf/localconf.php | sort -t = -k 2,2
```

(the sort says to use "=" as the field separator and then sort by the second field -- this will effectively sort by the value of $_db_host, and the -H grep output will tell grep to display the file name of the matching lines at the beginning.

Note you can pipe the output of the loop above as well:

```
for i in (/home/*/public_html/typo3conf/localconf.php); do
   grep -H '$_db_host =' $i /dev/null | tail -1
done | sort -t = -k 2,2
```

You can mix or match your tools as you desire!

another very useful tool is "cut" (with -d to specify the field separator), which you can use to pull apart the output.

(You can do all of these in perl and awk as well, but sometimes, especially for "one-offs," shell pipelines are easier)

Comment: hmm k - let me try to be a little more clear -and I will edit the question as well. 

In short - just need to know for all the localconf.php files on the server which database each points to -and in the localconf.php file there may be multiple entries of _db_host - we just need to list the last ones - and if possible sort them so we know which ones point where -   ie we have 40 that point to localhost  and list them   and then wewe have 20 that point to the db server 10.0.2.23 or wherever ...   

hoping that helps

Comment: OK, it sounds like something based on the last variant in my answer would be what you need -- it will take the last "$_db_host" line from each file, and then will sort that by the value of $_db_host, grouping them for you.   (If you want the db_host value first, and want to strip the "$_db_host =" from the output, easiest would probably be to use an awk construct like marcog suggests)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear, but this is an initial attempt:

```
grep "$_db_host" /home/*/public_html/typo3conf/localconf.php | \
    awk '{ print $1":"$3; }' | awk -F ':' '{ print $3": "$1 }' | sort
```

What that does is `grep`'s for `$_db_host` lines. You might want to use a regex to make it more robhust if there are possibly other strings there with the substring `$_db_host` that you don't want to match. It then uses two passes of `awk` to convert the lines into `'ip';: configfile` format. You can get rid of the quotes and semicolon with bash slicing if necessary, but if the format isn't strict you'll need a regex. Finally, it sorts the results so that matching IP addresses will follow one another (barring differences in quotes, which is why you might want to strip them).

Sample output:

```
'10.0.1.234';: /home/foo/public_html/typo3conf/localconf.php
'localhost';: /home/bar/public_html/typo3conf/localconf.php
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two questions here:

1. List the files that contain "`$_db_host = 'localhost';`".

   ```
    grep -l '^[ <t>]*$_dbhost[ <t>]*=[ <t>*]'localhost'[ <t>]*;' \
            /dev/null /home/*/public_html/conf/localconf.php
   ```

   I'm using `<t>` to indicate where the script might contain a tab; you might not need to be so cautious if you are sure your lines are rigidly formatted.
2. List the last host name (address) in a file that might also contain localhost entries (where the localhost entries are to be ignored).

   ```
    grep -l '^[ <t>]*$_dbhost[ <t>]*=[ <t>*]'[^']*'[ <t>]*;' \
            /dev/null /home/*/public_html/conf/localconf.php |
    grep -v "'localhost'" |
    sed 's/:[ <t>]*$_dbhost[ <t>]*=[ <t>]*'\([^']*\)';/ \1/' |
    awk '{address[$1] = $2}
        END { for (file in address) {
                  printf "%s %s\n", file, address[file];
              }
            }' | sort
   ```

   The `grep -v` and `sed` commands could be combined, but it is simpler to understand if they are not.  Unless this script is going to be used very often, the performance penalty is probably not worth worrying about.

   The first `grep` is a minor adaptation of the answer to Q1; it generates a list of file names (searching '/dev/null' won't find anything, but does ensure that if there is only one localconf.php file, the name is still listed).  The second `grep` eliminates localhost lines.  The `sed` command removes the debris, leaving just the file name and the host name in two space-separated fields, just the way `awk` likes its data presented.  The `awk` command uses an associative array keyed by the file name to record the last entry in a file; the assignment always overwrites any previous value.  The END block then prints out all the file names and the corresponding last `$_db_host` value set in the file.  The `sort` just lists the files in a deterministic order; the `for` loop order is not deterministic.  You could flatten the `awk` script onto one or two lines - I spread it over 5 to accommodate the limited line width in SO.

---

Addressing comment:

We can adapt my 'Part 2' answer - and fix the single-quote vs double-quote problem that is giving you the shell errors.

*Edited: dropped the unwanted `-l` option, and reinstating a missing `$`.*

```
 grep "^[ <t>]*\$_dbhost[ <t>]*=[ <t>*]'[^']*'[ <t>]*;" \
         /dev/null /home/*/public_html/conf/localconf.php |
 sed "s/:[ <t>]*\$_dbhost[ <t>]*=[ <t>]*'\([^']*\)';/ \1/" |
 awk '{address[$1] = $2}
     END { for (file in address) {
               printf "%s %s\n", file, address[file]; } }' |
 sort
```

This leaves the localhost entries in the list.  I've changed what was previously single quotes surrounding the `grep` regex and the `sed` script into double quotes.  That means that it is necessary to escape the `$` symbols.

---

Ignoring tabs:

```
 grep "^ *\$_dbhost *= '[^']*' *;" \
         /dev/null /home/*/public_html/conf/localconf.php |
 sed "s/: *\$_dbhost *= *'\([^']*\)';/ \1/" |
 awk '{address[$1] = $2}
     END { for (file in address) {
               printf "%s %s\n", file, address[file]; } }' |
 sort
```

I actually tested this with a series of trivial files instead of the great long complex /home/*/public_html/... path names - it worked OK.

```
JL: cat f1
$_dbhost = 'localhost';
JL: cat f2
$_dbhost = 'localhost';
$_dbhost = '9.12.23.34';
JL:
```

Etc.

Comment: very close - in short 1 Main Question

I need to know the last entry in each /home/*/public_html/conf/localconf.php for db_host='xxxxx';   (where xxxxx could be either local host and/or an ip address) 

I of course need to know if they are localhost or another ip 

I ran what you set - but it errored out stating

 bash: t: No such file or directory


I will give it a few tries - but any additional help is greatly appreciated  - the files are all pretty rigid - which helps a great deal

Comment: i think you have the closest answer - sadly still errors with the 

bash: t:  No such file or directory   :-(   

The file is pretty standard - how would this look if we got rid of the tab stuff ?   thanks again btw

Answer (score 0):

You regex-fu is weak.

```
> cat localconf.php
$_db_host = '10.0.1.234';

> grep -oP '(?<=\$_db_host = '\'').*(?='\'';)' localconf.php
10.0.1.234

> grep --version | head -n 1
GNU grep 2.5.4
```